# Force &nbsp; between the last two words in nextjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

On all application I build I keep manually adding   in between the last two words of all paragraphs to avoid widows as they are not as aesthetically pleasing. I’ve tried multiple ways of setting up plugins  for nextjs that build my code with that feature on.

I know it’s very easy to solve that on the client, but it would cause a layout shift on the first paragraphs and while you could add it manually that doesn’t feel like the correct solution. I honestly think that should be a css option, but I know there is none.

So I still wonder is there a way to let your application manipulate your JSX code before it becomes the HTML page it becomes?.

I was thinking another option is to just store the text somewhere else and always push it with   but that would require setting up a db connection where it’s not always necessary.

Answer (score 0):

1 . Create a custom Document component in your pages/_document.js file. This component is responsible for rendering the HTML document that Next.js generates.

2 . In the Document component, override the render method to modify the generated HTML. You can use the ReactDOMServer.renderToString method to render your app's JSX code to HTML, and then manipulate the HTML string before returning it.

Here's an example code:

```
enter code here
 import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
 import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'

 class MyDocument extends Document {
 static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
 const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
 return { ...initialProps }
 }

   render() {
   const { html } = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Main />)
   const modifiedHtml = html.replace(/(\s[\w'-]+)(\s[\w'-]+)(<\/p>)/gi, ' 
 $1&nbsp;$2$3')

    return (
    <Html>
    <Head />
    <body dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: modifiedHtml }} />
    <NextScript />
  </Html>
   )
 }
}

export default MyDocument
```

This code uses a regular expression to find all occurrences of two words separated by a space in a paragraph (

) tag, and replaces the space with a non-breaking space character ( ).

Note that this approach modifies the generated HTML directly, so it won't work if you're using client-side rendering (CSR) or static site generation (SSG) in Next.js. Also, this solution assumes that all your paragraphs are wrapped in a

tag.

I hope this helps you add the non-breaking space character between the last two words of your paragraphs in Next.js!

Comment: That looks like a ChatGPT response. I only need a nbsp between the last two words of a paragraph.

I’m looking for a solution that works with SSG.